# Como colocar uma <div> dentro de um iframe?

Tags: javascript, java, html, thymeleaf

Então, estou tentando fazer com que somente uma parte da minha pagina HTML se atualize, a cada "X" tempos. Estava tentando realizar isso através de AJAX, mas estava dando muitos problemas. Então resolvi mudar de plano.

Eis o meu problema:

Estou passando um model através do meu controller para um form no thymeleaf:

```
 <form id="formTest" class="form-inline" action="#" th:action="@{'log/'}" th:object="${log}" method="post">
      ...
</form>
```

Desse jeito consigo criar um objeto e então printar o seu conteúdo:

```
<p th:utext="${log.content}">Log content</p>
```

Consigo fazer oque quero atualizando toda a pagina, ou seja, consigo atualizar o conteúdo do meu objeto cada vez que eu atualizo a pagina. Mas a ideia é evitar que toda a pagina seja atualiza, logo, pensei em colocar esse conteúdo dentro de um iframe, e então atualizar o iframe a cada "x" tempos. Imagino que funcionaria do mesmo jeito... Algo como:

```
document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

O problema é que não consigo fazer com que esse conteúdo seja mostrado no iframe. Estava tentando desse jeito:

```
 <iframe id="logIframe" src="/log" width="950" height="500"> <!-- Meu iframe -->
    <div id="logDiv" class="panel-body">
       <pre>
          <p th:utext="${log.content}">Log content</p>
       </pre>
    </div>
 </iframe>
```

Mas não parece o jeito certo.

**Duvida:** Como coloco esse conteúdo dentro do iframe? É possível fazer isso direto no HTML? Ou de alguma outra maneira? Como faço?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta montar com essa lógica.

> - **1** - Coloque um **id** no parágrafo que quer atualizar
> - **2** - No seu código vc não precisará da **var num**, pois foi só para montar o exemplo, nem também do `log.text(num)`;
> - **3** - Na **var log** vc coloca o id que que colocou no Html, e pega o valor dela deste jeito `$("seu-id").text();`
> - **4** - No método **setInterval()***, vc chama a função e passa o valor do tempo que quer ao `p` para atualizá-lo.

```js
var num = 0;

function atualizar() {
  var log = $("#atlzr");          
  ++num;
 
  log.text(num);
}

setInterval(function() {
  atualizar();
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p th:utext="${log.content}" id="atlzr">Log content</p>
```

Basicamente sua função ficará assim:

```
function atualizar() {
  var log = $("#atlz").text();
}

setInterval(function() {
  atualizar();
}, 1000);
```

---

```
<p th:utext="${log.content}" id="atlzr">Log content</p>
```